# Create a database using T SQL on a specified location

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How to create a database using T SQL script on a specified location? Let's say, I want to create a SQL server database on `D:\temp\dbFolder`. How to do this?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

When you create the new database you specify the location. For example:

```
USE [master]
GO

    CREATE DATABASE [AdventureWorks] ON  PRIMARY 
    ( NAME = N'AdventureWorks_Data', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Data\AdventureWorks_Data.mdf' , SIZE = 167872KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 16384KB )
     LOG ON 
    ( NAME = N'AdventureWorks_Log', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Data\AdventureWorks_Log.ldf' , SIZE = 2048KB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 16384KB )
    GO
```

Answer (score 12):

From the SQL Server Books an example where database filenames are explicitely defined:

```
USE master
GO
CREATE DATABASE Sales
ON 
( NAME = Sales_dat,
   FILENAME = 'c:\program files\microsoft sql server\mssql\data\saledat.mdf',
   SIZE = 10,
   MAXSIZE = 50,
   FILEGROWTH = 5 )
LOG ON
( NAME = 'Sales_log',
   FILENAME = 'c:\program files\microsoft sql server\mssql\data\salelog.ldf',
   SIZE = 5MB,
   MAXSIZE = 25MB,
   FILEGROWTH = 5MB )
GO
```

Answer (score 4):

1. Create folder on your file system: D:\temp\dbFolder\
2. Run the script:

   ```
   USE master; 
   GO 
   CREATE DATABASE TestDB1  
   ON      ( NAME = Sales_dat, FILENAME = 'D:\temp\dbFolder\TestDB1.mdf') 
   LOG ON  ( NAME = Sales_log, FILENAME = 'D:\temp\dbFolder\TestDB1.ldf'); 
   GO
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Using variables in Studio Manager expanding on the previous examples.

Create folders and subfolders.
     Example: root folder E:\MSSQL\DATA
              subfolders E:\MSSQL\DATA\DB and E:\MSSQL\DATA\Logs.

```
MKDIR "E:\MSSQL\DATA\DB"
MKDIR "E:\MSSQL\DATA\Logs"
```

Change Database name @DBNAME variable @Test_DB' to your 'DesiredName_DB'

Change Root folder path @DataPath 'E:\MSSQL\DATA' to your as per above created folders.

Run the below in Studio Manager

```
DECLARE @DBNAME VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @DataPath AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @DBNAME = N'Test_DB'
SET @DataPath = N'E:\MSSQL\DATA'

SELECT @sql = 'USE MASTER'
EXEC (@sql)

SELECT @sql = 'CREATE DATABASE '+ quotename(@DBNAME) + ' 
ON 
PRIMARY
 ( 
 NAME = ''' + @DBNAME + '_DB'', 
 FILENAME = ''' + @DataPath + '\DB\' + @DBNAME + '.mdf'', 
 SIZE = 3136 KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, 
 FILEGROWTH = 1024 KB
 ) 
LOG ON
 (
 NAME = '''+ @DBNAME + '_Log'', 
 FILENAME = '''+ @DataPath + '\Logs\' + @DBNAME  + '_log.ldf'', 
 SIZE = 832KB , MAXSIZE =  2048 GB , FILEGROWTH = 10 %
 )'


EXEC (@sql)
```

Or another variation on the above theme.

```
DECLARE @DBNAME VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @DataFilePath AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @LogFilePath AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @DBNAME = N'Test_DB'
SET @DataFilePath = N'E:\MSSQL\DATA\DB\'
SET @LogFilePath = N'E:\MSSQL\DATA\Logs\'

SELECT @sql = 'USE MASTER'
EXEC (@sql)

SELECT @sql = 'CREATE DATABASE '+ quotename(@DBNAME) + ' 
ON 
PRIMARY
 ( 
 NAME = ''' + @DBNAME + '_DB'', 
 FILENAME = ''' + @DataFilePath + @DBNAME + '.mdf'', 
 SIZE = 3136 KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, 
 FILEGROWTH = 1024 KB
 ) 
LOG ON
 (
 NAME = '''+ @DBNAME + '_Log'', 
 FILENAME = '''+ @LogFilePath+ @DBNAME  + '_log.ldf'', 
 SIZE = 832KB , MAXSIZE =  2048 GB , FILEGROWTH = 10 %
 )'


EXEC (@sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

See this link : [CREATE DATABASE (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176061.aspx)

```
CREATE DATABASE [ADestinyDb] CONTAINMENT = NONE ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'ADestinyDb', 
  FILENAME = N'D:\temp\dbFolder\ADestinyDb.mdf' , 
  SIZE = 3136 KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, 
  FILEGROWTH = 1024 KB )
LOG ON 
( NAME = N'ADestinyDb_log', 
  FILENAME = N'D:\temp\dbFolder\_log.ldf' , 
  SIZE = 832KB , MAXSIZE =  2048 GB , FILEGROWTH = 10 %)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create folder on your file system: D:\temp\dbFolder\ and run the below script
(try 'sa' login)

```
 USE master
CREATE DATABASE [faltu] ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'faltu', FILENAME = N'D:\temp\dbFolder\faltu.mdf' , SIZE = 2048KB , FILEGROWTH = 1024KB )
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'faltu_log', FILENAME = N'D:\temp\dbFolder\faltu_log.ldf' , SIZE = 1024KB , FILEGROWTH = 10%)
```