# How to restore SQL server database from external drive without uploading database to local hard disk?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2014

I am running win7 on a VM. I have Microsoft SQL Server 2014 downloaded on the VM. I have an external drive with a .bak file that I wish to restore a database with. The database is 400+ GBs. My local disk cannot support a database of this size, but my external drive can. How do I run SQL Server locally and restore from and keep the database files externally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create database then configure it for files run on external drive. Then try to restore it.
Creating db on another folder example here: [Create a database using T SQL on a specified location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120917/create-a-database-using-t-sql-on-a-specified-location)

Comment: I am sorry I am such a beginner, but where am I writing the code do these things? Where are those files located? Its not all in the command line, is it?

Comment: you can run command in sqlcmd.exe or you can use any db managament tools (sql management studio, navicat, toad, etc)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, search for DBCC TRACEOFF(1807), e. g.:

http://sql-articles.com/articles/general/day-2trace-flag-1807attach-network-data-file/